# Restore more than 250 files using DPM 2010 and PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scdpm

I've got what should be a fairly simple task: restore the following files from DPM:

`D:\inetpub\wwwroot\*\index.*`

I followed the instructions [in this TechNet wiki](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/576.how-to-use-a-windows-powershell-script-to-recover-an-item-in-data-protection-manager-en-us.aspx) and pretty much thought I had it.

Unfortunately, the `New-SearchOption` commandlet can only return 250 results, and this search would generate way more results than that. So actually only the first 250 files were restored, which is no use to anybody.

Does anyone know of any way to get around the 250 search results limit? I guess it would be possible to get the subdirectories of `D:\inetpub\wwwroot` and loop through them in turn, but I kind of want to keep this fairly simple as it is only for this task.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the DPM implementation of Powershell but it looks like if native DPM cmdlets won't let you get over 250 items you're going to have to get them one at a time.  Try something like this:

```
gci D:\inetpub\wwwroot -Recurse -File -Filter index.* | % { New-SearchOption $_ }
```

Comment: Cheers for answering! Unfortunately the time when this would have been useful has passed so I can't verify whether this works :)

Comment: At least it might be helpful for the next guy that comes around.